# MySQL - DATETIME greater than given time regardless of date

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a table which stores time data in the `DATETIME` format.  I would like to build a query to return just the values after a give time (for example 15:00 - i.e. 3pm) for each day, not just for a given date.

Is this possible in MySQL.  Does anyone have any examples?

Comment: What means 1500?  is 1500 minutes after stored date?

Comment: 15:00 (as in 3pm) each day.  I will amend the question so that it is clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `hour()` function:

```
where hour(col) >= 15
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
 WHERE TIME(column) >= '15:00:00'
```

or even

```
 WHERE TIME(a.column) >= TIME(b.cutoff)
```

Comment: Simple and straightforward!